# 500 Internal Server Error with bare git repo after post-receive hook

Tags: php, linux, git, centos, cpanel

I think this is the last issue I am having with setting up Git on this dedicated server (with cpanel).

I have created a bare repo on my PC, placed it on the server: `/home/cpaneluser/git-repos/`

Edited `/home/cpaneluser/git-repos/myproject.git/hooks/post-receive` and it's contents are:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/cpaneluser/public_html GIT_DIR=/home/cpaneluser/git-repos/myproject.git git checkout -f
```

I gave it 0764 permission so the owner can execute it. It seems to get executed fine because it does actually put the files of my repo into my public_html directory as expected.

I then navigate to the domain in my browser and get an Internal Server Error with it's generic, unhelpful, error message `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

What is really weird, is if I manually edit the 'index.php' file located in the webroot 'public_html', it seems to magically fix everything. However, doing this edit puts the get repo out of sync with my local end.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting an internet server error after running the 'post-receive' hook, which performs a `checkout -f`. And how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Found one in suphp_log: `[Fri Jan 16 17:27:08 2015] [warn] File "/home/cpaneluser/public_html/index.php" is writeable by group`.  The files are being created with 0664 when they should be 0644. So I guess now, why are the files created with the wrong permissions, and how to remedy it?

Comment: post-receive hook needs umask set. At the start of the script, I added: `umask 0022` and it created the files with 0644 permissions, and the internal server error is now gone. Works perfectly now! - @PaulCrovella if you want to submit it as an answer, I will accept it for you ;)

Comment: @PaulCrovella I know :) However, due to some cool people here on SO, my rep was hurt and I had a question or two down voted. I can not post answers, I get "We are not accepting answers from this account". Which sucks, I did nothing wrong. I asked a question, gave as much info as I could, and got down voted with nobody saying why. Just a hit and run. I think if I get enough rep I will soon be able to answer questions. I just figured I should give someone the selected answer, and also get the rep for it to help recover my account's rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `umask 0022` solved my permission problems.

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 0022
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/cpaneluser/public_html GIT_DIR=/home/cpaneluser/git-repos/myproject.git git checkout -f
```